# How to remove class with Javascript

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname

Another Newbie Question:
I am attempting to completely remove a class from the DOM when the screen.width is smaller than or equal to 320 px.
Attempting this without specifying a screen width works just fine. The class is removed from the page, but when I attempt to specify the conditional screen width it does not.
Can anyone help me out here?
This is what I have:

```
<div class="poison">Poison Text</div>

<script>
var p = document.getElementsByClassName('poison');
var cstr = "poison";
var poison = screen.width;

if (poison <= 320) {
    (var i = p.length; --i >= 0;) {
        var n = p[i];
        while (n.className.split(" ").indexOf(cstr) == -1) {
            n = n.parentNode;
        }
        n.parentNode.removeChild(n);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: It looks like you tried to write a `for` loop `(var i = p.length; --i >= 0;  )` and forgot the `for`

Comment: What is `(var i=p.length; --i>=0;)` supposed to be doing? Is this an `if` statement? A `for` loop? In its current state this snippet of code will not achieve anything.

Comment: You should have your developer console open while testing your code.

Comment: ...also, I don't see the purpose of the `while` loop. You already know that the `n` element has that class, so why attempt to traverse through its ancestors?

Answer (score 2):

You should use media queries instead of JS for this. Add this line to your stylesheet

```
@media (min-width:320px){


}
```

and put the class/classes you wish to use at sizes above 320px inside.

You can use max-width and multiple conditions as well.

Comment: Doing it with a media query removes it from sight but the element still exists and takes up space. I would like to use javascript to remove it from the DOM thus making the space available on the page when rendered.